# Pins not working and show error on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I create first application with a book, and i got problem.

I should write

```
rails g scaffold pins description:string
```

and then

```
rake db:migrate

heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Now my website should works on `myLinkFromHeroku.herokuapp.com/pins`

But it does not work, i see only:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

What i should do now ? Why this not working ? "logs" is "latest activity" ? I see only `build succeesded`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your console run `heroku logs -n 1500` to see logs. Hope this logs will provide more info. 1500 is max number of lines limit in heoku.

Latest activity on heroku web is not logs.

Comment: i found this, but i maked heroku run rake db:migrate ----------ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "pins" does not exist

Comment: Error saying you didn't run heroku run rake db:migrate. Please make sure this command run successfully on your machine

Comment: now i see "Cannot run more than 1 Free size dynos."

Comment: You have two connection to heroku from console. So try terminate previous connection. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727605/heroku-cannot-run-more-than-1-free-size-dynos look this link for help.