# Database not migration to Heroku(cloud9)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, cloud9

I kept getting the error `Cannot run one-off process at this time. Please try again later.`
when i try heroku run `rake db:migrate`  on ruby on rails on cloud9. I already `$ git push heroku master` and I use postgesSQL. What's happening?

```
remote:        /tmp/build_34cdeb640ff2f18ebfc3cba992dc4fa0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to daeshaun-todo-app.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/daeshaun-todo-app.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/daeshaun-todo-app.git
```

'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heroku: Cannot run more than 1 Free size dynos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727605/heroku-cannot-run-more-than-1-free-size-dynos)

Comment: did you google your error message?

Comment: Yes but everyone has different version of the problem

Comment: can you add the complete log of the task. and run it with rake db:migrate --trace